# Generic Dictionary containing Generic Dictionary in Spring.Net

Tags: c#, spring, dictionary, spring.net

I have an object that contains a property:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<ContextMenuItemModel>>> ContextMenuModel { get; set; }
```

How do I use Spring.Net to configure this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, configuring this in xml isn't pretty, consider switching to Spring.Net code config to [configure your spring context in C#](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/refdoc/migration-example.html#d4e73).

Anyway, to do this in xml, you use the constructors of the generic .net collections. For instance, `List<T>` takes an `IList<T>` constructor, so you can configure a list of strings as follows:

```xml
<object id="list1" type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;string>">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list element-type="string">
      <value>abc</value> 
      <value>def</value> 
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

Note that in xml you have to use `&lt;`, because using `<` isn't legal xml. Setting generic collection values is discussed [in the Spring.net docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-generic-collections-values).

A generic `Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>` can be configured in a similar manner, which is also discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5147812/322283):

```xml
<object id="dic1" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;string>>">
  <constructor-arg>
    <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;string>">
      <entry key="keyToList1" value-ref="list1" />
      <entry key="keyToList2" value-ref="list2" /> 
    </dictionary>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

And you probably see the next one coming now:

```xml
<object id="dic0" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;string>>>">
  <constructor-arg>
    <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;string>>">
      <entry key="keyToDic1 " value-ref="dic1" />
    </dictionary>
  </constructor-arg>  
</object>
```

Which can be injected:

```xml
<object id="MyObject" type="MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly">
  <property name="ContextMenuModel" ref="dic0" />
</object>
```

This isn't really pretty, but you can slightly [improve the readability of your xml using type aliases](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-creation-generic-types).

Comment: Wowww...
So, if the list should include "ContextMenuItemModel" items, the xml line of id="dic0" will be:
    <object id="dic0" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;View.Model.ContextMenuItemModel>, View.Model>>">    
?

Comment: Its not work

The XML:
<object id ="WorkspaceTreeModelDicProp" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string,System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;ContextMenuItemModel>,ElmoMotionControl.View.Model>>">
<constructor-arg>
<dictionary key-type="string" value-type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
&lt;string, System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;ContextMenuItemModel>,ElmoMotionControl.View.Model>">
<entry key="SystemConfiguration_Workspace" valueref="SystemConfiguration_Workspace"/>
</dictionary>
</constructor-arg> 
</object>

Whats wrong?

Comment: The Exception is:
Initialization of object failed : Cannot resolve type [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary                               <string, System.Collections.Generic.List                                     <ContextMenuItemModel>, ElmoMotionControl.View.Model>>] for object with name 'WorkspaceTreeModelDicProp' defined in file [C:\Projects\EAS090412\View\ElmoMotionControl.View.Main\bin\Debug\SpringConfiguration\ContextMenusSpringConfiguration.xml] line 19

Comment: This is difficult to debug ... I think the err is somewhere here: `System.Collections.Generic.List <ContextMenuItemModel>, ElmoMotionControl.View.Model` which might attempt to find the `System.Collections.Generic.List` in the `ElmoMotionControl.View.Model` assembly. Try `System.Collections.Generic.List<REPLACE_WITH_FULLNAMESPAE.ContextMenuItemModel>` and leave out `,ElmoMotionControl.View.Model`.